# JsonConverter Excel VBA - HTTP get always same

Tags: json, vba, excel

I am retrieving some JSON data from an HTTP service and using JsonConverter to parse it.

When I first run the macro everthing is fine, but when I run the macro again I get same the same data as the first time (when I should be getting updated data, which includes a ticker changing every 100 ms at the client side).

If I close Excel and reopen again I get the latest data.

What is the problem here?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the caching mechanism.

To avoid it, use `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` instead of `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0`.

You could also keep using `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0`, but you'll have to set the following header:

```
xhr.SetRequestHeader "If-None-Match", "-"
```